# error message in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

if you please help me out i can not find out whats wrong with the above code since i am learning on my own asp.net c# with the above code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("alert('Organizer added!');");
        Response.Write("</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Response.Write(Ex.Message);
    }

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's not working? what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
RegisterStartupScript("...");
```

to write script dynamically on page

```
 if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientscript"))
 {
        string script1 = @"<script language=JavaScript>
                         alert('Organizer added!');
                          </script>";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "clientscript", script1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, it is displaying the alert. What are you trying to get your code to do? Are you trying to access a control on the client side?

Just as an FYI, the script block you're entering is actually added before your .. block.
For example, when you View Source, it looks like this...

```
<script>alert('test');</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
....
```

You should use @danyolgiax's idea by registering the script using the ClientScriptMananger, instead of Response.Write.